# Why bootstrap is pointing to .less files?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have installed css only bootstap CSS using bower. On closer inspection I found out that is is somehow using .less file which doesn't exist on my machine. This is not making any sense to me. I'll appreciate if someone can shed some light on this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you hover over the name of one of the .less files, what pops up?

Comment: @ZAD-Man It goes to buttons.less file which doesn't exist machine.

Comment: That should be the result of clicking on it, but what appears in the pop up when you _hover over_ it?

Comment: Hovering displays that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because bootstrap.css has

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */
```

at the end of the file.

bootstrap.css is the result of combined .less [files](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less) so in order to easier debug the bootstrap, you can have an idea where some classes come from.

If you remove **sourceMappingURL** from bootstrap.css, you won't see any .less files in dev console.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks for clarifying this.